# Add new Eclipse project to multi-project repository layout in Subversion (with Subversive)

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository, commit, subversive

I have the following svn layout:

```
org.example
-- trunk
---- org.example.core
---- org.example.test
---- org.example.target
...
-- branches
-- tags
```

In Eclipse, I have imported the single Eclipse projects (org.example.core, etc.) as Eclipse projects (sounds redundant but I hope you know what I mean), i.e., all projects are located in the workspace root.

Now I have created a new Feature Project in Eclipse (org.example.feature) and want to add that to my Subversion repository, and into the existing folder structure (i.e., `org.example` > `trunk` > `org.example.feature`).

I cannot work out how to do this with the Subversive plugin. On right-click on the project I have only "Share Project" (and "*s") as options, and when I click Share, I only get "Simple Mode"...

I have tried committing to org.example and org.example.trunk, but Subversive always "says" the directory exists already...

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only get "Simple Mode"

Are you sure? Have you tried activating "Advanced Mode" via the radio button?

This should give you the option to choose "Use multiple project layout with the specified root name:".

Simply give *org.example* as root name and activate "Use Subversion recommended layout". This should work with your layout.

Make sure to check the "preview".